# E4 Exception org.eclipse.core.commands.common.NotDefinedException

Tags: eclipse, exception, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm experiencing a weird behavior in our Eclipse e4 RCP application. We're getting an exception that is simply being printed to StdErr, and which seems to originate from some e4 framework logic deeper down.

The exception is reliably replicable when firing up the application, opening a new dialog (MWindow.class), and opening a Nebula DateChooserCombo inside that dialog.

However, we don't get the exception when the e4 Spy plug-ins are activated in the run configuration. So I looked at the differences of the regular and the spy run configuration. With some trial and error I was able to figure out that when I add the plug-in "org.eclipse.ui" and its required plug-ins the exception doesn't occur any longer.

Now my two questions are:

1) Considering the exception below, is adding "org.eclipse.ui" to the list of loaded plug-ins the correct way to go or is it overkill and just a workaround?

2) If "org.eclipse.ui" is the solution, what is the easiest way to tell PDE to also package this plug-in and its required plug-ins with the final Eclipse RCP Product?

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.common.NotDefinedException: Cannot get the parent identifier from an undefined context. org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialog
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.Context.getParentId(Context.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.getLevel(ContextSet.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.compare(ContextSet.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.compare(ContextSet.java:1)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:265)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:190)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet.<init>(ContextSet.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTableManager.createContextSet(BindingTableManager.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingServiceImpl.setContextIds(BindingServiceImpl.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener$3.widgetDisposed(ShellActivationListener.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1118)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:725)
    at zzz.tools.widgets.datechooser.ZzzDateChooserCombo.dropDown(ZzzDateChooserCombo.java:1072)
    at zzz.tools.widgets.datechooser.ZzzDateChooserCombo.popupEvent(ZzzDateChooserCombo.java:767)
    at zzz.tools.widgets.datechooser.ZzzDateChooserCombo$1.handleEvent(ZzzDateChooserCombo.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1118)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2193)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4659)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1633)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

The following stack trace was created when a normal JFace MessageDialog was opened in the same application. Different use case --> same error:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.common.NotDefinedException: Cannot get the parent identifier from an undefined context. org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialog
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.Context.getParentId(Context.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.getLevel(ContextSet.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.compare(ContextSet.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet$CComp.compare(ContextSet.java:1)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:265)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:190)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.ContextSet.<init>(ContextSet.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTableManager.createContextSet(BindingTableManager.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingServiceImpl.setContextIds(BindingServiceImpl.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activate(EclipseContext.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener$2.run(ShellActivationListener.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.activate(ShellActivationListener.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.handleEvent(ShellActivationListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1266)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1673)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2193)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4659)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1633)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Decorations.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:330)
    at zzz.dialogs.StatusmeldungDialog.openNotification(StatusmeldungDialog.java:83)
    at zzz.parts.warnings.display.WarningsPart$3.onFinished(WarningsPart.java:228)
    at zzz.actions.ZzzBackgroundJob$1$2.run(ZzzBackgroundJob.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Comment: Including org.eclipse.ui in an e4 app is definitely wrong. What is `ZzzDateChooserCombo` and what is it doing at line 1072?

Comment: @greg-449 That is our implementation of the nebula DateChooserCombo.  Line 1072 is code which is copied straight from the dropDown() method of the super class nebula AbstractCombo. This is definitely not the problem. In fact, this is only one way of getting the exception. Opening a regular JFace MessageDialog also gives you the error. I will add an additional stack trace.

Comment: Just a guess but have you defined the `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialog` binding context in the Application.e4xmi (you should)?

Comment: Man, that was truly amazing! Perfect guess, my problem is solved! Thank you so much.
Now that you're pointing it out I found the section in Lars Vogel's tutorial (35.2. JFace default values for binding contexts). So easy to miss. I don't know if this could be helpful for anybody else, but I'll accept you're answer right away if you write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Eclipse cannot find the `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialog` binding context.

You need to define the default Binding Contexts in the Application.e4xmi.

The base context should be `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow` and it should have two children `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window` and `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialog`